# How to overwrite eager loaded property in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

If I have something like this:

```
$book = App\Book::with('authorInfo')->first();
```

How can I set $book->authorInfo to a new value?
I'vet tried to set it like this:

```
$book->authorInfo = 'test';
```

but it didn't change the value.

When I return $book from my controller method the property authorInfo is transformed to snake case.

```
{
    book: {
        author_info: null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short version: you can use [setRelation](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_setRelation) method provided by the Eloquent model.

Suppose your `App\Book` model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
    }
}
```

And your `App\Author` model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Author extends Model
{
    public function books()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
    }
}
```

When you fetch the book and eager load the author relationship, you can then replace this relation with the new instance of `Author` model using `setRelation` method:

```
// Fetch book and load the author.
$book = App\Book::with('author')->first();

// Create a new instance of author.
$newAuthor = new App\Author;
$newAuthor->name = 'John Doe';
$newAuthor->save();

// Replace the loaded relation.
$book->setRelation('author', $newAuthor);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Tried using set relation but it didn't work. Doing unset($book->author); then setting $book->author = 'test'; works but its not really elegant.

Comment: I don't want to save a new related model, only set some defaults for that property when no authorInfo is found for the book.

Comment: Well, you don't have to save/store it in the database, no need to call `$newAuthor->save()`. You can even pass any value to `setRelation` method: `$book->setRelation('authorInfo', 'test')`, does not have to be `Author` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to point to the author, and then change the name of this

```
$book->author->author = 'test';
```

Hope this can help you

Or you can try directly modify your the propertie "author_info" doing this: `$book->author_info = 'test';`

Comment: $book->author is the property I'm trying to change.

Comment: When you use "With" statement, you really do an extra query, retrieving extra data related with the original query. Your query means you have a book an want to retrieve the author that is in another table

Comment: I get that it is loading data with another query but why do you have an author property on the first author property in your example?

Comment: if you first table is book (id, id_author, book) and the second table is author (id, author), you need to first indicate the relationship (author table) and then the propertie (author), but if your propertie is called name, must to be $book->author->name :)

Comment: I want to overwrite all of $book->author